# onDisconnected method not called in signalR

Tags: signalr

working on chat application using SignalR.
onDisconnected() is called after some time but not immediately in the chrome browser when the user closes or logged out.
But in the Firefox browser, it does get called immediately.

After using
this code in JS

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {     
               $.connection.hub.stop();
           };
```

now it is working in the Chrome browser
but then onDisconnected() is called very late when the user get logged out from the Firefox browser

please help
Can't find any worked so it works in all browser

Thank you

Comment: If you do a google search you will find many results (several right here on SO) that state not to use window.onbeforeunload. Adding an event listener for 'beforeunload' appears to be the direction - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: I used event listener but the behaviour is different in both browser. As chrome takes time and in Mozilla, it's done immediately.

Comment: You may want to check the docs for changing the disconnect timeout, which defaults to 30 seconds. This is how long the SignalR waits before the disconnect event is raised. It may be that Chrome does not properly trigger the event and the disconnect is not graceful but is disconnected on the client side. The server side won't do anything for 30 seconds. Docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#how-to-change-timeout-and-keepalive-settings

Comment: yes, it waits 30 sec to get disconnected.